# android search view on another Activity

Tags: android, searchview

I'm Creating a Search View Sample Project;
I have 3 Activities:

**MainActivity**(Direct you to search Activity)

**SearchActivity**(You can see search View and type whatever you want)

**SearchResultActivity**(Will Process your Search request)

and in Manifest file I have

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.searchsample.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".SearchActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable"  />
</activity>


<activity android:name=".SearchResultActivity">

</activity>
```

if I press search button; I can see the new SearchActivity Opens ;

if I move the **intent-filter** Part from **.SearchActivity** to **.SearchResultActivity**; I no longer can Search anything; (Because the .SearchResultActivity never run)
how can I solve this Problem;
I want, when I Press the search button, see result on .SearchResultActivity

Comment: did u solve that problem.

Comment: No; do you have any suggestion? this code works find; but if I wanna see the result search in ".SearchResultActivity", I no longer can Search any thing; because the event for searching doesn't raise

Comment: i am trying for the same, i will get to you when ever i got a solution.